# how to send a value from views.py to base.html everywhere on site?

Tags: django, footer, django-urls

I want to have a section with latest posts in my footer throughout my web site. My footer is located in base.html.

How can I have this:

```
def footer(request):
return render_to_response('base.html', {'posts_latest':Post.objects.order_by('-published'),},)
```

on every page? To have it shown I have to connect the function with an url, and I can't do that with all of them.

I tried this [context processors tutorial](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/), but I kept getting the error:

```
Error importing request processor module myapp.app.context_processors: "No module named context_processors"
```

so I abandoned that idea.

What do you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A custom context processor is what you are looking for, so you are already on the right track. You should try to solve your import problem. What django version are you running? Where is your processor located?

Comment: Url -> one view -> one rendered template. But template can extend another template and include multiple others. You do not have to write view for a part of page, except this part is loaded asynchronously by ajax. However, as @Jingo mentioned, context processor is what you need.

Comment: I am using Django 1.4 and my processor is located in the views.py files, the generic one, outside of all specific apps. def footer(request):
    return {'posts_latest':Post.objects.order_by('-published'),}
 this is it.

Comment: I figured it out! It is that I was following the pattern and not thinking. I was supposed to write myapp.views.footer. Thanks for helping me get the the answer with the question where it is located. If you write your answer I will choose it as solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom context processor is what you are looking for, so you are already on the right track. You should try to solve your import problem. What django version are you running? Where is your processor located?